# VBScript Removing a network shortcut if it exist

Tags: shell, vbscript

I am trying to check to see if a network location shortcut is in my Network Shortcut if it exist delete it and make another one called homedrive. How ever it makes the homedrive but doesnt delete the old one. the old one is registered by username hense why i used %username%. i just need help with the deleting

Thank You in Advance

```
Const NETHOOD = &H13&

Set objWSHShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")


Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(NETHOOD)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
strNetHood = objFolderItem.Path


Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Networkpath = Shell.SpecialFolders("NETHOOD")
shortcut = Networkpath & "\%username%.lnk"
If FSO.FileExists(shortcut) Then 
    FSO.DeleteFile shortcut
End If

strShortcutName = "HomeDrive"
strShortcutPath = "\\homer-2\IT$\%username%"

Set objShortcut = objWSHShell.CreateShortcut _
    (strNetHood & "\" & strShortcutName & ".lnk")
objShortcut.TargetPath = strShortcutPath
objShortcut.Save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
>> Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>> Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>> sFSpec = FSO.BuildPath("%HOME%", "tmp.txt")
>> WScript.Echo CStr(FSO.FileExists(sFSpec)), sFSpec
>> sFSpec = Shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(sFSpec)
>> WScript.Echo CStr(FSO.FileExists(sFSpec)), sFSpec
>>
False %HOME%\tmp.txt
True C:\Documents and Settings\eh\tmp.txt
>>
```

proves that the FSO does not expand environment variables automagically. So

```
shortcut = Networkpath & "\%username%.lnk"
If FSO.FileExists(shortcut) Then
```

will never be true. Use `Shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings()`.

Comment: yes your method works but it doesnt work on hidden paths the location of the folder im trying to get to is hidden

Comment: Actually it worked perfectly the shell.expandenviromentstrings() thank you.